# Display next div on click

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

Say I have the following HTML layout:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="comment">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="data">
        <img src="image.png" class="image-click" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="open-me"></div>

  <div class="comment">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="data">
        <img src="image.png" class="image-click" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="open-me"></div>

  <div class="comment">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="data">
        <img src="image.png" class="image-click" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="open-me"></div>
</div>

... etc ...
```

How would I make it so that if you click the image in one of the `comment` classes, it shows HTML in the `next` `open-me` class?

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".image-click", function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'show_html.php',
      type: "POST",
      success: function() {
        $(this).find(".open-me").html(); /* this is where I'm stuck */
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome, you are not sending any param .. without that there is no need of GET/POST:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside your AJAX success method isn't referring to the clicked element anymore. For that, we can set a context variable of `this`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".image-click", function() {
    var self = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'show_html.php',
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            self.parents(".comment").next(".open-me").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Didn't work. :/ It's returning data, but it's never showing it.

Comment: @Burrows -- Well you have to do something with that `data`. I've added a parameter to your `success` function and added it to the HTML, try with the new code.

Comment: I actually have data set in my code, but removed it because I didn't think it would be important. Nevertheless, it's still not working. :/

Comment: What's your console say about it? -- @Burrows

Comment: it shows `POST http://localhost/website/show_html.php 200 OK 14ms`. It's returning data as it should, but it's not displaying it.

Comment: Run a `console.log(data)` in the success callback, whats the log say -- @Burrows

Comment: @Burrows -- I updated the selector in the success, try again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to access the sibling open-me. Also, you should save a reference to $(this) outside of the .ajax().

```
// outside the ajax function
var that = $(this);

// inside the ajax function
that.parent(".comment").next("open-me").html();
```

jQuery's documentation about [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) is relevant.

Comment: OK, so maybe you need to actually set some HTML? If you don't pass anything into .html() it returns it. If you pass something in, like .html("<p>blah blah</p>") it will set it.

Comment: I actually am passing data to it, but didn't include it here. Nevertheless, it's still not working even with data. :/